# Should I create an ensemble by averaging deep models' weights and biases?

Tags: neural-networks, ensemble-learning

- When I train deep models with [cosine annealing learning-rate scheduling and warm restarts](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.03983), I get models that achieve completely different scores on my validation set, after each training cycle.
- There seems to be no relationship between the scores on the validation set and the actual number of training cycles run since the very beginning, i.e., there seems to be no overfitting or underfitting from cycle to cycle, as from cycle to cycle, the validation scores go either up or down, inconsistently.
- It looks like each training cycle produces completely different models as if I would train the network from scratch many times with different random seeds (that impact the training set shuffling and thus the batches).

##### My question is whether creating a final model with the mean weights and biases of all learned models is a good approach. Is there literature that supports or opposes this approach with experiments?

Comment: Just a thought: federated learning averages over independently trained models. Not sure if it will help you

Comment: Thank you. I have found Pytorch documentation for [Stochastic Weight Averaging (SWA)](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#weight-averaging-swa-and-ema). Is it related to "federated learning"?

Comment: Looks more like an option to an optimizer to me

Comment: Can you add your model architecture here and a toy data example to see if you have any setup issues?  Also what is the underlying problem you try to solve / predict?  Why do you think it's predictable in the first place?  Last: averaging weights/ bias terms of same model over time is "maybe" sthg worth trying; across different re-rtrains of sane model architecture you shouldn't do that as weights/bias terms can be permuted to give same model predictions. Averaging weights wouldn't make sense in that case